# Integrate compiled vue-cli project into JSP, tomcat

Tags: vue.js, jsp, vue-cli

I have a question regarding setting up the project with JSP and Vue-cli.

The old project developed with standalone Angular, tomcat, and JSP with an entry point.

The application starts with the index.jsp and it gets the data from the java like

`<c:if test="data.parameter.isLogin!=1}">`

basically, all the front-end controllers and views are imported with `<script>` tag in index.jsp file.

back to the question, I have a vue-cli based project and want to integrate this into jsp file.

Would it be possible to run the application with compiled Vue project which compiled with [disabled index generation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#disable-index-generation) and
import compiled app.js with `<script>` tag and start the project?

Thank you and any concerns and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue with build the Vue based project first and put them in the JSP assets folder. call those files with `<script>` tag from the entry point and it worked well.